# checking if a web page has compression enabled with php

Tags: php, gzip, deflate

I want to check if a web page has gzip/deflate compression enabled with php. Probably with get_headers I won`t make it, so a anydvices, or any bit of code anywhere to check this ( couldn't find anything on the subject ). Probably I need to find in the headers for the compression, how do i make a HTTP request with compression enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and use [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php),
set CURLOPT_ENCODING to gzip,deflate

if the webpage is gzip/deflate enabled,
the encoding request will be respect and gzip content will be returned